# C++ Export array from DLL to invoke/use in C based program

Tags: c++, arrays, import, export, invoke

Hello I am currently trying to export an array from a Dll into a C-based data-analysis program called Uniplot.
I am able to call the DLL and get it running, though I cant access the data provided by the Dll. I am not really well-served on this subject but I am guessing it has something to do with releasing the function to get rid of the pointers, or the data type in general even.

**Header.h**

```
 // considering export into C application
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

    // prepare functions for later export/import from DLL
#ifdef CALC_EXPORTS
#define CALCDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)

#else
#define CALCDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)

#endif

typedef double t_mda[150];
typedef double t_sda[50];
typedef double t_oda[150];

/*===========================
        functions
============================*/

        // general function
CALCDLL_API double* CALC (t_mda MDA, t_sda SDA);

....

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

**.cpp**

```
t_oda ODA;

CALCDLL_API double* CALC (t_mda MDA, t_sda SDA) {

...

//data output

return ODA;

}
```

CALC is generating the data and saving it to the ODA-array which I would like to use in another application. What are the changes I need to make to get that running?

Comment: What does it mean you cannot access the data ? Are you calling CALC and it returns a null pointer ?

Comment: I need to define the array ODA as an empty array in the application I want to import the data into. If I print the array its empty.

Comment: Any ideas anyone?

Comment: How do you determine that the C array is empty?